# Replacing string with greater/smaller than symbol is not replaced

Tags: r

I want to clear a table from unwanted characters. The table can be downloaded here freely: https://www.aggdata.com/free/germany-postal-codes
It contains all german postal codes, and since in Germany there are some special characters like ü,ö,ä or ß, I need to swap them to other symbols.
Now let's say I want to replace all "ß" by "ss".
I used this code, collected from different posts in Stack Overflow. My code looks like this:

```
postal <- read.csv("~/Downloads/de_postal_codes.csv")
postal <- as.data.frame(sapply(postal,gsub,pattern="<df>",replacement="ss"))
```

When I try to replace other strings for testing like `pattern = "Cot"` the code works, but not if it contains the `<>` symbols. What is the problem here?
I am using R 3.3.3 in RStudio 1.0.136 on MacOS 10.13.4.

Comment: The first column is integer.  I guess you wanted to loop through only certain columns instead of the whole dataset

Comment: It isn't working either when I address a specific column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. If you put `encoding = "UTF-8"` in to the `read.table` command, you see that `<df>` comes back as `\xdf`. I don't know much about this area, but trying this with the original encoding seemed to work. Hope this helps

```
postal <- read.table("~/Downloads/de_postal_codes.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
postal$Place.Name[4]
postal <- as.data.frame(
  sapply(postal, function(x){
    gsub(pattern="\xdf", replacement="ss", x=x)
  }) 
)
postal$Place.Name[4]
```

edit: Also, I don't think you're `sapply` was doing the trick. The `x` parameter in `gsub` is not the first variable when you do `?gsub`.

edit2: I'm using windows & 3.5.0 R version